# From Matrix to List

Tags: python, list, matrix

I want to get a list of coordinates from a Matrix, how to do that?

So I want a list in which every element is a pair of number and eliminate the pair that are counted more than once.

Example:

```
A=array[[1, 2, 34, 1],
        [2, 4, 38, 0],
        [3, 2, 34, 4],
        [4, 2, 4, 2] ]
```

So now I have a matrix 4x4 and I want to put into a list the 2nd and 3rd columns, such that:

```
list= [(2,34), (4,38), (2,34), (2,4) ]
```

And eliminate the pairs that are counted twice so in my example the pair:

```
(2,34)
```

since it is counted twice will be removed so the new list will be:

```
 list_new=[(4,38), (2,4)]
```

Consider that my starting matrix should be very large, thus I want to avoid "for".
Thanks in advance to who will answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st part - you can use itemgetter with map/zip/list.

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_list = list(zip(map(itemgetter(1),A), map(itemgetter(2),A)))
print(my_list) # [(2, 34), (4, 38), (2, 34), (2, 4)]
```

Then to get the duplicates values you can use collection counters.

```
import collections
dup_list  = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(my_list).items() if count > 1]
print(dup_list) # [(2,34)]
```

Now, to remove these values from the list use filter.

```
for item in dup_list:
    my_list = list(filter(lambda a: a != item, my_list))
print(my_list) # [(4, 38), (2, 4)]
```